# tsql - How do I parse a full name to pull out first name from these possible values

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring

--How do I pull out first name using tsql from the possible values in a FullName field:

Here are possible values:

1. Richardson M.D., Asha R
2. Goines PHD, Jennifer
3. Goines P.H.D., Kevin G
4. Bourne M.D., T. David

From the below query, I am able to pull last name fine, but I am not able to get first name correctly.  Is it possible with the type of data values?

```
select 
SUBSTRING(pe2.full_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', pe2.full_name) - 1) AS "Rendering Provider:  LastName",
SUBSTRING(pe2.full_name, CHARINDEX(', ', pe2.full_name) + 1, len(pe2.full_name)) AS "Rendering Provider:  FirstName",
parsename(replace(pe2.full_name, ' ', ','), 3) as FirstName,
from personnel pe2
```

Comment: Been a while since I've seen this question asked. Some recommended reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). TL;DR: you don't, any assumptions you make will be wrong, and thus will result in wrong results. If you need to know the parts of the name separately, then you should be storing them separately.

Comment: You have no idea the can of worms you are opening. Separating names is not a solved problem, even when you have dedicated libraries designed for the task. There are more edge and corner cases around this than you can believe.

Comment: Is `'McCartney C.H. M.B.E., Sir Paul'` a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

For the data posted in the question, and making no assumptions about other formats of data:

```
DROP TABLE #n;
CREATE TABLE #n (full_name nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO #n (full_name)
VALUES ('Richardson M.D., Asha R'),
('Goines PHD, Jennifer'),
('Goines P.H.D., Kevin G'),
('Bourne M.D., T. David');

SELECT SUBSTRING(full_name,PATINDEX('%, %',full_name)+2,LEN(full_name)), full_name
FROM #n
```

Answer (score 0):

parsename doesn't work that way, it returns values from a specified position in a "Dot" delimited string.
Example: I have a cat

```
select parsename(replace('I have a cat', ' ', '.'), 4) as FirstWord
select parsename(replace('I have a cat', ' ', '.'), 3) as SecondWord
select parsename(replace('I have a cat', ' ', '.'), 2) as ThirdWord
select parsename(replace('I have a cat', ' ', '.'), 1) as FourthWord
```

Try this instead to understand how it is parsing the firstname

```
parsename(replace(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(pe2.full_name, CHARINDEX(', ', pe2.full_name) + 1, len(pe2.full_name))), ' ', '.'), 2) AS FirstName 
parsename(replace(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(pe2.full_name, CHARINDEX(', ', pe2.full_name) + 1, len(pe2.full_name))), ' ', '.'), 1) AS MiddleName 
from personnel pe2
```